# Updated Rivets.JS two-way binding example

Tags: javascript, rivets.js

I've been looking around but couldn't find any updated tutorial/example for 2-way data binding using [Rivets.JS](http://rivetsjs.com/)

I'm using the 0.6.9 version as it is the one advertised on its website.
The two-way binding example provided gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'adapters' of undefined
```

Does anyone have a working example (using v0.6.9) of it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example,

```
rivets.bind($('#auction'), {
  auction: auctionModel,
  controller: controllerObject
})
```

I couldn't get filters working though. http://jsbin.com/kubawa/1/.

Are you using a custom adapter, extend your question, and I will extend my example with an adapter.